# How to return a 401 code from a Custom Authorization Attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a custom authorization attribute.

When this is implemented in WebAPI the `OnActionExecuting` method is passed an `HttpActionContext` object, which I can update the response in, e.g.

```
actionContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

But, when implemented in MVC the object passed is a `ActionExecutingContext` object, which contains a response but it is read-only, meaning I can't return an authorization rejection in the same way.

This won't work as it's read only:

```
context.HttpContext.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

This also won't work as it's read only:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response = new System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

How can I get a writable response in MVC that I can set in this way?

Comment: This is a pretty good resource: https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging

Comment: Sounds like you are doing custom ActionFilter instead of AuthorizationFilter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the result, not the response;

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Authorization code here - if not authorized:

    filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the .NET Core 6 application I used: [UnauthorizedResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.unauthorizedresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

```
public class AuthenticatedUsersAttribute : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.HttpContext.User.Identity;
        IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
        var email = claims.First(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value;
        if (email == "pwujczyk@gmail.com")
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do: HttpException: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx

```
throw New HttpException(401, "your message");
```

Comment: in a middle of an Attribute this gonna break the app, at least it will stop it's debug it will cause confusion because the api user will receive no answer..